# Problema com extensão JSON no phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, json, phpmyadmin, extension

Olá, precisei fazer a reinstalação do servidor (apache, php, mysql e phpmyadmin) e estou tendo esse erro ao acessar a página `localhost/phpmyadmin`. Antes disso estava dando o mesmo problema mas com a `mbstring`. Essa última eu resolvi mas não consigo resolver o problema que está no print: extensão json.

Lembro que isso já aconteceu anteriormente comigo, mas não lembro como resolvi.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Alguma ideia de como resolver? Obrigado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou instalar a extensão `json` do php? se tiver usando ubuntu seria algo do tipo `sudo apt install php7.2-json`

Comment: sim, já tentei, inclusive a saída do comando é que a extensão já é a mais recente. Reinstalei de novo depois e começou a dar problema com a extensão mysqli e não mais com a json...

Comment: Acho que é problema nos repositórios que estou usando, mais tarde vou reinstalar tudo de novo, mas se alguém já passou por esse problema e lembra como resolvê-lo pode mandar